# Javascript Array inside Array in For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

my friends. I have the following situation. The first loop works very well. But the second seens to not recongnize the "can[i]". I just tried to use "{}" on the second Array, but I think I'm doing it wrong. I'll need also to call these variables in future "if" statements. Thank you.

```
        for (g=0; g<256; g++) {
            document.write('<canvas id="canvas' + g + '" width="8" height="8"></canvas>');
        }

        for (g=0; g<256; g++) {
            document.write('<div id="chr'+g+'"></div>');
        }


    var can = [], ctx = [];
    for (var i=0; i<256; i++){
        can[i] = document.getElementById("canvas" + i);
    }

    for (var i=0; i<256; i++){
        ctx[i] = can[i].getContext('2d');
    }
```

Comment: You can set can[i] and ctx[i] in the same loop. That code seems fine if you have 256 canvases in the DOM already though, but maybe you're problem has to do with something else. Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can we see all of your code?

Comment: Yes, I have 256 canvases in the DOM. They were generated by loop. My doubt is about the format to use in the second array.

Comment: This code works for me. What means that second loop does not recognise `can[i]`? Is there any error in JS console? Try if value of `document.getElementById` is not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code works fine**, however you are testing the values or your assumptions about what should be stored is erroneous. (example: http://jsbin.com/tanesicoti/1/edit?js,console).

However it is very inefficient for what it does. A better way to write it in a single loop, and without having to search the DOM afterwards is like so (http://jsbin.com/zozocikanu/2/edit?js,console):

```
var can = [], ctx = [];

/*
 * Create a node in memory so that we can store the elements inside it
 */
var canvasFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var divFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

/*
 * Initialise our loop variables
 */
var canvasCount = 256;
var canvas;
var div;
for (var i = 0; i < canvasCount; i++) {

  /*
   * Create a canvas element and insert it into its fragment
   */
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 8;
  canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas' + i);
  canvasFragment.appendChild(canvas);

  /*
   * Create a div element and insert it into its fragment
   */
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('id', 'chr' + i);
  divFragment.appendChild(div);

  /* 
   * Get our array values, objects are passed by reference so
   * even though our elements aren't in the DOM yet, this variable
   * will point to the same item after we do.
   */
  can[i] = canvas;
  ctx[i] = canvas.getContext('2d');
}
/*
 * Insert our items into the DOM. This is much faster as the browser
 * has to repaint when you insert items, but as we insert them in two
 * actions and not 512 (2 * 256) we create 2 repaints and not 512.
 */
document.body.appendChild(canvasFragment);
document.body.appendChild(divFragment);

console.log(ctx[123], ctx.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your function `document.getElementById` cannot find specified `id` and returns `null`. Please, check if you have all elements from `id="canvas0"` to `id="canvas255"`.

Also important is that they do not have and prefix (e.g. `id="canvas001"` will not be found but `id="canvas1"` will be)